# Faceting dynamic fields in Solr

Tags: dynamic, solr, filter, facet, faceted-search

I am looking to develop a basic product filter system based on attributes in Solr. The attribute field names can vary from product to product so I assumed setting up dynamic fields in the schema based on each data type supported. This way I can specify ranges for attributes I know will be are numeric.

For example:

```
{ID:12345, Colour:Blue, Length:0.3}
```

After some reading it seems that Solr does not support the faceting of dynamic fields. I have considered implementing an Entity-Attribute-Value system by setting up an multi-valued 'attribute' field and data will appear as:

```
{ID:12345, attributes:["Colour:Blue", "Length:0.3"]}
```

The above works however I fear that it will be limiting in the long run and would prevent me from performing range methods.

Any advice and alternate methods would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what makes you think that solr does not support the faceting of dynamic fields?

Comment: My apologies I wasn't clear - obviously solr can facet dynamic fields but I'm unable to specify the fields I want faceted as they vary based on the products attributes. Is there some sort of wildcard way I can specify which will get facet all fields with a certain prefix/suffix?

Comment: got it. Then I would say that the approach proposed by you is quite good.